# How to update chromium daily builds manually

Tags: upgrade, updates, google-chrome, chromium

I've downloaded and ran the chromium from http://download-chromium.appspot.com/ to receive daily builds of chrome for ubuntu. But I can't find a way to manually update it.
Yes, there is a repository dedicated for it (https://launchpad.net/~chromium-daily/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) but it got discontinued.

I there a way to apply updates for chromium manually?

Comment: From http://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/download-chromium, there are a couple of scripts at https://github.com/scheib/chromium-latest-linux that you can run.

Comment: This is for Xenial Xerus?

Comment: @andrew.46 OP does not appear to mention a version. The raw build that used to be available at link at Question could be run at most dists; see https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!searchin/chromium-discuss/chromium%2420snapshot|sort:date/chromium-discuss/YL4GAwoWfZU/btt-ioX0AwAJ. The bounty is for how to install or run raw build of latest beta, dev or unstable version of chromium

Comment: @guest271314 OIC. Looks reasonably straightforward from these 2 pages: 1. Build deps - https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/build/install-build-deps.sh 2. Download and compile - http://dev.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code . I am working though and will probably be unable to catch your generous Bounty. Interesting question though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install this `ppa` ["Canonical Chromium Builds" team](https://launchpad.net/~canonical-chromium-builds/+archive/ubuntu/stage)

```
  $ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:canonical-chromium-builds/stage
  $ apt-get update
```

Use `build-dep` action of `aptitude` before installing `chromium-browser`

```
  $ aptitude -v -V build-dep chromium-browser
  ..
  The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Upgrade the following packages:                                         
  1)    ..
  Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] y
  ..
  $ sudo aptitude install chromium-browser
```

See also [How to install latest package version of a ppa?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/828443/how-to-install-latest-package-version-of-a-ppa)

Comment: This command crashing hard disk after update chromium in ubuntu 14.04. Let me know why that crash happening after update chromium my two laptops crashed because of this answer. Please accept answer after fully verified.

Comment: @Prabu Not sure how the commands could cause hard drive to crash?

Comment: That's what i couldn't understand something went wrong. I already tried this command with two laptops after that same crash is happened. That's why i need solution for this, atleast this will avoid another crash.

Comment: @Prabu Did not crash, here. Though did not try at 14.04. How much disk space and RAM are available at laptops?

Comment: RAM 4 GB and Hard disk 500 GB Free Disk space 100 GB

Comment: @Prabu Why do you need to use `aptitude -v -V build-dep` at 14.04? Can you not use the `ppa` alone?

Comment: We cannot install chrome using `ppa` alone. Thats why i tried with,

`$ aptitude -v -V build-dep chromium-browser`

Then why you mention `aptitude` command here, atleast you have to mention ubuntu version? Any problem with `aptitude` command please update.

Comment: @Prabu _"We cannot install chrome using `ppa` alone."_ Are you referencing chrome or chromium? For chromium `$ sudo apt-get install chromium-browser` should install newest version of chromium

Answer (score 0):

When you boot your computer it automatically checks updates.  It run the `apt-check` application.  You can run this manually at any time with:

```
$  /usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check
```

You can use the `-p` argument to show the package names that have been upgraded.  Like most applications you can use `-h` to show and describe other parameters.

If you want to specifically filter for updates to Chromium you can run:

```
$  /usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check -p | egrep chromium
```

To upgrade the applications run:

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
```

To resynchronize information about about the packages use:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

It's recommended to run `update` prior to running `upgrade` or `dist-upgrade`

Like most Linux applications you can get details about this tool with:

```
$ man apt-get
```