# Chromium is not working in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, chromium

This is the error I get at command line:

> /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser: error while loading shared libraries: libatomic.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

But when clicking on the chromium icon at the left menu it is exiting automatically rather opening it.

Comment: Is libatomic installed? At least in 16.04 there is a package called `libatomic1`

Comment: What method did you use for installing Chromium?

Comment: Actually I was going to update the chromium version initially which I was using in 12.04 LTS. But certainly I can't assure what was happened during the installation. Since then my chromium was not even opening. After clicking on the icon itself chromium is becoming invisible. Now whenever I am running through the terminal I get this error message in console. How can I search for libatomic ? Can anybody helps me in this regard ?

Comment: New versions of Chromium do not work on 12.04.

Comment: @Pilot6 _"New versions of Chromium do not work on 12.04."_ Can you provide further details? Version 51 from https://launchpad.net/~canonical-chromium-builds/+archive/ubuntu/stage did load and run; though just tried to install version 52.0.2743.116-0ubuntu0.12.04.1.1015 where same error OP details occurred.  See also http://askubuntu.com/questions/828443/how-to-install-latest-package-version-of-a-ppa/830282#830282.

Answer (score 5):

There are several steps to get *the very latest* `chromium-browser` package running on Precise Pangolin, but I have succeeded and so should you!

**1. Install from PPA:**

This PPA is not recommended for general use but worked well on my Precise Pangolin system:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:canonical-chromium-builds/stage
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

`chromium-browser` will not work out of the box as you have experienced until a few other issues are attended to...

**2. Missing libatomic:**

You will see an error when loading `chromium-browser` from the command line: a missing library `libatomic.so.1`. You can search for this missing file by using the great utility `apt-file`:

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file
apt-file update
```

(This creates a *local* index rather than a *system* one, use `sudo apt-file update` if you want a *system* index.)

You will be prompted to download file indices and you should accept this prompt and allow the download. Then search for the missing file:

```
andrew@ithaca:~$ apt-file search libatomic.so.1
gcc-mozilla: /usr/lib/gcc-mozilla/lib/libatomic.so.1
gcc-mozilla: /usr/lib/gcc-mozilla/lib/libatomic.so.1.0.0
gcc-mozilla: /usr/lib/gcc-mozilla/lib32/libatomic.so.1
gcc-mozilla: /usr/lib/gcc-mozilla/lib32/libatomic.so.1.0.0
andrew@ithaca:~$
```

You can see that it is part of the `gcc-mozilla` package which you can install as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-mozilla
```

Note that shared libraries are *not sourced* from the `gcc-mozilla` installation location as demonstrated here:

```
andrew@ithaca:~$ ldconfig -v 2>/dev/null | grep -v ^$'\t'
/usr/local/lib:
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa-egl:
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa:
/lib32:
/usr/lib32:
/lib:
/usr/lib:
andrew@ithaca:~$
```

So we add *an extra path* for `chromium-browser` with a slight variation of the technique demonstrated by @Renaud:

```
sudo touch /etc/ld.so.conf.d/chromium-browser.conf
echo "/usr/lib/gcc-mozilla/lib" | sudo tee -a /etc/ld.so.conf.d/chromium-browser.conf
sudo ldconfig
```

And you will now see the added search path:

```
andrew@ithaca:~$ ldconfig -v 2>/dev/null | grep -v ^$'\t'
/usr/lib/gcc-mozilla/lib:   <------------- Here!
/usr/local/lib:
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa-egl:
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa:
/lib32:
/usr/lib32:
/lib:
/usr/lib:
andrew@ithaca:~$
```

**Note**: *If you try the* `aptitude build-dep chromium-browser` *method this step (adding the LD path) will still need to be followed...*

But still more errors:

**3. Missing  libXss.so.1:**

You will then get an error message:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libXss.so.1:
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Once again `apt-file` will locate the appropriate package:

```
andrew@ithaca:~$ apt-file search libXss.so.1
libxss1: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXss.so.1
libxss1: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXss.so.1.0.0
libxss1-dbg: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXss.so.1.0.0
andrew@ithaca:~$
```

And then install this library as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install libxss1
```

And that should do it as `chromium-browser` has no problem finding the library once installed!

**4. Running the browser:**

Running nicely here:

```
andrew@ithaca:~$ chromium-browser --version
Chromium 52.0.2743.116 Built on Ubuntu , running on Ubuntu 12.04
andrew@ithaca:~$
```

And the obligatory screenshot:

[image]

*Click for full sized image....*

And have fun :)

**References:**

- [Debian Wiki: apt-file](https://wiki.debian.org/apt-file)
- [SO: How to print the ld(linker) search path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922949/how-to-print-the-ldlinker-search-path)

Comment: Have you tried `aptitude build-dep` approach? Should return same result, yes?

Comment: @guest271314 I have not tried the `build-dep` approach although google and Ask Ubuntu shows that several have used this approach successfully. I prefer the 'cleaner' approach that I have demonstrated in my answer where specific packages are searched out and installed. It is a matter of choice :)

Comment: @guest271314 For the sake of completion I used the `aptitude` method  on a clean VM and found the same libatomic error message which required the fix as illustrated above. After this all ran smoothly though....

Comment: Interesting. Curious why using `aptitude build-dep` appeared to install necessary dependencies, here?

Comment: @guest271314 It is really used when you wish to re-compile a package rather than drag in missing run-time requirements...

Comment: Tried `apt-file update` at drive having low disk space, had to  `CTRL-C` as available disk space approached 0.

Comment: @guest271314 If you load the cache to your `$HOME`directory it will be in `~/.cache/apt-file` and will take up close to 100 MB...

Comment: Perhaps at a disk with greater space `apt-file` would be an applicable solution. `aptitude build-dep chromium-browser` returned expected result, here, without consuming remainder of available disk space.

Comment: See also [How to update chromium daily builds manually](http://askubuntu.com/questions/823252/how-to-update-chromium-daily-builds-manually/)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after upgrading.
I installed the "gcc-mozilla" package, then updated LD so that it loads the library, as described below:

```
$ sudo -i
# apt-get install gcc-mozilla
# echo "/usr/lib/gcc-mozilla/lib" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/chromium-browser.conf
# ldconfig
# exit
```

Chromium should now load gracefully.

Comment: Is there any better tutorial to understand ubuntu command and about the OS ? How could you find that ?

Comment: username@username-PC:~$ chromium-browser
/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser: error while loading shared libraries: libXss.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: The above was the error when running chromium from the terminal

Answer (score 1):

Use `aptitude build-dep` to install dependencies before installing `chromium-browser`

```
$ aptitude -v -V build-dep chromium-browser
..
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Upgrade the following packages:                                         
1)     gtk2-engines-pixbuf [2.24.10-0ubuntu6 (now, precise) -> 2.24.10-0ubunt
2)     libgail-common [2.24.10-0ubuntu6 (now, precise) -> 2.24.10-0ubuntu6.3 
3)     libgail18 [2.24.10-0ubuntu6 (now, precise) -> 2.24.10-0ubuntu6.3 (prec
4)     pciutils [1:3.1.8-2ubuntu5 (now, precise) -> 1:3.1.8-2ubuntu6 (precise
Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] y
```

See this [Answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/832105/92739) at [How to install latest package version of a ppa?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/828443/how-to-install-latest-package-version-of-a-ppa)

Comment: I tested this method and encountered the same issue with libatomic not appearing in the LD path. Fix was simple, as illustrated in 2 of the other posts in this Q&A...

Comment: @andrew.46 _"I tested this method and encountered the same issue with libatomic not appearing in the LD path."_ Interesting. Received error described at Question before using `aptitude build-dep`. Used `aptitude build-dep chromium-browser`, and am now composing this comment at chromium 52, without any errors being logged.