# How to install latest package version of a ppa?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, ppa, chromium

Have installed `ppa` ["Canonical Chromium Builds" team](https://launchpad.net/~canonical-chromium-builds/+archive/ubuntu/stage) with

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:canonical-chromium-builds/stage
```

which previously installed chromium version 51.0.2704.79.

Am attempting to install the newest version of chromium available at the `ppa` for `Precise`.

```
$ lsb_release -a
```

returns

```
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS
```

When trying

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

the following is logged at `terminal`

```
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/canonical-chromium-builds/stage/ubuntu/ precise/main chromium-browser i386 52.0.2743.116-0ubuntu0.12.04.1.1015
```

where the newest version in above `ppa` for [`Precise`](https://launchpad.net/~canonical-chromium-builds/+archive/ubuntu/stage?field.series_filter=precise) is listed as

```
chromium-browser 53.0.2785.89-0ubuntu0.12.04.1.1018 (2016-09-07)
```

Trying

```
$ sudo apt-cache policy chromium-browser
```

logs

```
Candidate: 52.0.2743.116-0ubuntu0.12.04.1.1015
```

How to install the latest version of the `ppa`? Or, alternatively, the latest version 53+ `dev` build of chromium-browser at `Precise`?

Comment: Looking at each dist, Xenial is the only one with version 53 in its Release file. (http://ppa.launchpad.net/canonical-chromium-builds/stage/ubuntu/dists/xenial/) But on the front page of the PPA it clearly shows version 53 for Precise, Trusty, and Xenial. I'm stumped.

Comment: @SuperSluether Did build fail https://launchpad.net/~canonical-chromium-builds/+archive/ubuntu/stage/+build/10720014 ?

Comment: The 12.04 build was canceled, and the 14.04 build has a dependency wait. 12.04 says canceled on lgw01-18, so maybe a dependency problem?

Comment: @SuperSluether Are there any workarounds for installing latest version of chromium?

Comment: The source code is still available, so you could download and compile it yourself I guess: https://launchpad.net/~canonical-chromium-builds/+archive/ubuntu/stage/+files/chromium-browser_53.0.2785.89.orig.tar.xz

Comment: I did some more digging, and it looks like someone canceled the 12.04 builds on purpose. The 14.04 builds are waiting on other packages to be built, and the 32-bit package for 16.04 failed to build.

Comment: @SuperSluether This used to be an option [Download Chromium](https://download-chromium.appspot.com/) , though appears to have been discontinued [Chromium Continuous no longer updated (no longer exists)](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!searchin/chromium-discuss/chromium$20snapshot|sort:date/chromium-discuss/YL4GAwoWfZU/btt-ioX0AwAJ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use `aptitude`s `build-dep` action, where dependencies for `chromium-browser` from ["Canonical Chromium Builds" team](https://launchpad.net/~canonical-chromium-builds/+archive/ubuntu/stage) were installed before installing chromium, resulting in version `52.0.2743.116 (Developer Build) Built on Ubuntu` being successfully installed at Precise 12.04.1.

```
$ aptitude --help

Usage: aptitude [-S fname] [-u|-i]
       aptitude [options] <action> ...
  Actions (if none is specified, aptitude will enter interactive mode): 
 ..
 build-dep    - Install the build-dependencies of packages.
 ..
```

After adding `ppa`,

```
$ aptitude -v -V build-dep chromium-browser
Unable to satisfy the build-depends: Build-Depends: libgcrypt-dev.
Unable to satisfy the build-depends: Build-Depends: libexpat-dev.
Unable to satisfy the build-depends: Build-Depends: libpng-dev.
Unable to satisfy the build-depends: Build-Depends: libxslt-dev.
Unable to satisfy the build-depends: Build-Depends: libsrtp-dev.
Unable to satisfy the build-depends: Build-Depends: libgcrypt-dev.
Unable to satisfy the build-depends: Build-Depends: libexpat-dev.
Unable to satisfy the build-depends: Build-Depends: libpng-dev.
Unable to satisfy the build-depends: Build-Depends: libxslt-dev.
Unable to satisfy the build-depends: Build-Depends: libsrtp-dev.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
## list of packages
..
Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] n
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

      Upgrade the following packages:                                         
1)     gtk2-engines-pixbuf [2.24.10-0ubuntu6 (now, precise) -> 2.24.10-0ubunt
2)     libgail-common [2.24.10-0ubuntu6 (now, precise) -> 2.24.10-0ubuntu6.3 
3)     libgail18 [2.24.10-0ubuntu6 (now, precise) -> 2.24.10-0ubuntu6.3 (prec
4)     pciutils [1:3.1.8-2ubuntu5 (now, precise) -> 1:3.1.8-2ubuntu6 (precise

Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] y
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  binutils-gold [2.22-6ubuntu1.4]  chrpath [0.13-2build2]  
  dh-buildinfo [0.9ubuntu1]  gir1.2-gconf-2.0{a} [3.2.5-0ubuntu2]  
  gir1.2-gnomekeyring-1.0{a} [3.2.2-2]  
  libatk1.0-dev{a} [2.4.0-0ubuntu1]  
  libatomic-ops-dev [7.2~alpha5+cvs20101124-1ubuntu1]  
  libcairo-script-interpreter2{a} [1.10.2-6.1ubuntu3]  
  libcairo2-dev{a} [1.10.2-6.1ubuntu3]  libcap-dev [1:2.22-1ubuntu3]  
  libcups2-dev [1.5.3-0ubuntu8.7]  
  libevent-core-2.0-5{a} [2.0.16-stable-1ubuntu0.1]  
  libevent-dev [2.0.16-stable-1ubuntu0.1]  
  libevent-extra-2.0-5{a} [2.0.16-stable-1ubuntu0.1]  
  libevent-openssl-2.0-5{a} [2.0.16-stable-1ubuntu0.1]  
  libevent-pthreads-2.0-5{a} [2.0.16-stable-1ubuntu0.1]  
  libexif-dev [0.6.20-2ubuntu0.1]  libffi-dev [3.0.11~rc1-5]  
  libfontconfig1-dev{a} [2.8.0-3ubuntu9.2]  
  libfreetype6-dev{a} [2.4.8-1ubuntu2.3]  
  libgconf2-dev [3.2.5-0ubuntu2]  libgconf2-doc{a} [3.2.5-0ubuntu2]  
  libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev{a} [2.26.1-1ubuntu1.5]  
  libgnome-keyring-dev [3.2.2-2]  libgtk2.0-dev [2.24.10-0ubuntu6.3]  
  libjpeg-dev [8c-2ubuntu7]  
  libjpeg-turbo8-dev{a} [1.1.90+svn733-0ubuntu4.4]  
  libjpeg8-dev{a} [8c-2ubuntu7]  libjsoncpp-dev [0.6.0~rc2-2]  
  libjsoncpp0{a} [0.6.0~rc2-2]  libnspr4-dev{a} [4.12-0ubuntu0.12.04.1]  
  libnss3-dev [2:3.23-0ubuntu0.12.04.1]  
  libpam0g-dev [1.1.3-7ubuntu2.3]  
  libpango1.0-dev{a} [1.30.0-0ubuntu3.1]  libpci-dev [1:3.1.8-2ubuntu6]  
  libpixman-1-dev{a} [0.30.2-1ubuntu0.0.0.0.3]  
  libspeechd-dev [0.7.1-6ubuntu3]  libspeechd2{a} [0.7.1-6ubuntu3]  
  libspeex-dev [1.2~rc1-3ubuntu2]  libudev-dev [175-0ubuntu9.10]  
  libwebp-dev [0.1.3-2.1ubuntu1]  libwebp2{a} [0.1.3-2.1ubuntu1]  
  libxcb-render0-dev{a} [1.8.1-1ubuntu0.2]  
  libxcb-shm0-dev{a} [1.8.1-1ubuntu0.2]  
  libxcomposite-dev{a} [1:0.4.3-2build1]  
  libxcursor-dev{a} [1:1.1.12-1ubuntu0.1]  
  libxdamage-dev{a} [1:1.1.3-2build1]  
  libxfixes-dev{a} [1:5.0-4ubuntu4.4]  libxft-dev{a} [2.2.0-3ubuntu2]  
  libxi-dev{a} [2:1.7.1.901-1ubuntu1~precise3]  
  libxinerama-dev{a} [2:1.1.1-3ubuntu0.1]  
  libxml2-dev [2.7.8.dfsg-5.1ubuntu4.15]  
  libxrandr-dev{a} [2:1.3.2-2ubuntu0.3]  
  libxrender-dev{a} [1:0.9.6-2ubuntu0.2]  libxss-dev [1:1.2.1-2]  
  libxtst-dev [2:1.2.0-4ubuntu0.1]  
  ninja-build [1.3.4-1.1ubuntu0.14.04.1~12.04]  
  x11proto-composite-dev{a} [1:0.4.2-2]  
  x11proto-damage-dev{a} [1:1.2.1-2]  
  x11proto-fixes-dev{a} [1:5.0-2ubuntu1]  
  x11proto-randr-dev{a} [1.4.0+git20120101.is.really.1.4.0-0ubuntu1~precise2]  
  x11proto-record-dev{a} [1.14.1-2]  
  x11proto-render-dev{a} [2:0.11.1-2]  
  x11proto-scrnsaver-dev{a} [1.2.1-2]  
  x11proto-xinerama-dev{a} [1.2.1-2]  
The following packages will be upgraded:
  binutils [2.22-6ubuntu1 -> 2.22-6ubuntu1.4]  
  fontconfig-config [2.8.0-3ubuntu9.1 -> 2.8.0-3ubuntu9.2]  
  gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 [2.26.1-1 -> 2.26.1-1ubuntu1.5]  
  gtk2-engines-pixbuf [2.24.10-0ubuntu6 -> 2.24.10-0ubuntu6.3]  
  libcups2 [1.5.3-0ubuntu4 -> 1.5.3-0ubuntu8.7]  
  libevent-2.0-5 [2.0.16-stable-1 -> 2.0.16-stable-1ubuntu0.1]  
  libfontconfig1 [2.8.0-3ubuntu9.1 -> 2.8.0-3ubuntu9.2]  
  libfreetype6 [2.4.8-1ubuntu2 -> 2.4.8-1ubuntu2.3]  
  libgail-common [2.24.10-0ubuntu6 -> 2.24.10-0ubuntu6.3]  
  libgail18 [2.24.10-0ubuntu6 -> 2.24.10-0ubuntu6.3]  
  libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 [2.26.1-1 -> 2.26.1-1ubuntu1.5]  
  libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common [2.26.1-1 -> 2.26.1-1ubuntu1.5]  
  libgtk2.0-0 [2.24.10-0ubuntu6 -> 2.24.10-0ubuntu6.3]  
  libjpeg-turbo8 [1.1.90+svn733-0ubuntu4.1 -> 1.1.90+svn733-0ubuntu4.4]  
  libpam0g [1.1.3-7ubuntu2 -> 1.1.3-7ubuntu2.3]  
  libpci3 [1:3.1.8-2ubuntu5 -> 1:3.1.8-2ubuntu6]  
  libpixman-1-0 [0.24.4-1 -> 0.30.2-1ubuntu0.0.0.0.3]  
  libudev0 [175-0ubuntu9.2 -> 175-0ubuntu9.10]  
  libxcb-render0 [1.8.1-1ubuntu0.1 -> 1.8.1-1ubuntu0.2]  
  libxcb-shm0 [1.8.1-1ubuntu0.1 -> 1.8.1-1ubuntu0.2]  
  libxcursor1 [1:1.1.12-1 -> 1:1.1.12-1ubuntu0.1]  
  libxfixes3 [1:5.0-4ubuntu4 -> 1:5.0-4ubuntu4.4]  
  libxi6 [2:1.6.0-0ubuntu2 -> 2:1.7.1.901-1ubuntu1~precise3]  
  libxinerama1 [2:1.1.1-3build1 -> 2:1.1.1-3ubuntu0.1]  
  libxml2 [2.7.8.dfsg-5.1ubuntu4.2 -> 2.7.8.dfsg-5.1ubuntu4.15]  
  libxrandr2 [2:1.3.2-2 -> 2:1.3.2-2ubuntu0.3]  
  libxrender1 [1:0.9.6-2build1 -> 1:0.9.6-2ubuntu0.2]  
  libxtst6 [2:1.2.0-4 -> 2:1.2.0-4ubuntu0.1]  
  pciutils [1:3.1.8-2ubuntu5 -> 1:3.1.8-2ubuntu6]  
The following packages are SUGGESTED but will NOT be installed:
  libcairo2-doc  libgtk2.0-doc  libpango1.0-doc  speech-dispatcher

$ sudo aptitude -v -V install chromium-browser
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  chromium-browser [52.0.2743.116-0ubuntu0.12.04.1.1015]  
  chromium-browser-l10n{a} [52.0.2743.116-0ubuntu0.12.04.1.1015]  
  chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra{a} [52.0.2743.116-0ubuntu0.12.04.1.1015]
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the **repo's** `Packages.bz2` file for 12.04 and 16.04 and saw that there `Packages.bz2` were not updated to point to the latest version of chromium available in the repo.

Maybe the maintainer forgot to do it

So I would recommend you to use another ppa or wait beacuse the **repo's** *devel* section which ,if I am right means that the update is still in testing process and not ready as considered by the maintainer .

And as you asked how can you install then you may use these commands:
`cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d`
`sudo nano canonical-chromium-builds-ubuntu-stage-xenial.list`
and change the line : 
`deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/canonical-chromium-builds/stage/ubuntu precise main`
to 
`deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/canonical-chromium-builds/stage/ubuntu xenial main`
and then run 
`sudo apt update && sudo apt install chromium-browser`

[**Before editing the source file**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIjlW.png)
[**After editing the source file**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erQOr.png)

Comment: Are you suggesting to install `Xenial` dist version of package at `Precise`?

Comment: Yup!!!   You can try it..

Comment: Were you able to successfully install chromium at `Precise` using `Xenial` package?

Comment: To be clear I am a **xenial** user and installed many precise packages like `Atom, conky themes, NoobsLab themes` and I can you will be able to do it considering that you are in an _**LTS**_ release  and they are kept updated with the latest stable software... So in theory a **xenial** packages will install and run in **precise**

Comment: Interesting. Have you done the same the other way? That is, install `Xenial` packages at `Precise`? Or newer dist packages at older dist? Found [LTSEnablementStack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack), which appears to update `Precise` kernel to `Trusty`

Comment: You don't need to update your kernel to use browser like Chromium and it should work without creating any trouble but please this is the way I do and it may or may not work on precise

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45983/discussion-between-guest271314-and-joe-green).

Answer (score 0):

The PPA you mention is a testing site used just before upload to Ubuntu main. Things there are either new and broken and not ready to use, or landing in the distro anyway in a few days. You shouldn't use it ***unless asked to***.

It appears that the major version you are interested in for Precise is currently building at the time of this post as shown [i386](https://launchpad.net/~canonical-chromium-builds/+archive/ubuntu/stage/+build/10978652) and [amd64](https://launchpad.net/~canonical-chromium-builds/+archive/ubuntu/stage/+build/10978649)

Edit: Both of the above failed to build on icy01-31. The build logs for [amd](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/287706992/buildlog_ubuntu-precise-amd64.chromium-browser_53.0.2785.143-0ubuntu0.12.04.1.1026_BUILDING.txt.gz) and [i386](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/287706732/buildlog_ubuntu-precise-i386.chromium-browser_53.0.2785.143-0ubuntu0.12.04.1.1026_BUILDING.txt.gz) may be of interest to you.

Perhaps patience will pay off. I would assume that they will be released if they are successfully built. I believe once successful it will be available [here](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/chromium-browser/?C=M;O=D)

Source:

https://launchpad.net/~canonical-chromium-builds/+archive/ubuntu/stage

Comment: The linked build failed https://launchpad.net/~canonical-chromium-builds/+archive/ubuntu/stage/+build/10978652 . Solved issue by using `aptitude build-dep` before installing, which resulted in successful install of `version 52.0.2743.116 (Developer Build)`